# Add days to date format MM/dd/yyyy in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

The question is simple, how to add days to this date format:

MM/dd/yyyy like 11/06/2015

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
    String format = "mm/dd/yyyy";
    String date = "11/06/2015";
    SimpleDateFormat simpleFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy");

    java.text.DateFormat df = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(format);
    java.util.Calendar calendar = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();

    try {
        calendar.setTime(df.parse(date));
        calendar.add(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, +1);
        String formatted = simpleFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
        System.out.println(formatted);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + ex.toString());
    }
```